# Weapon index sets index values to the same

Tags: 2d, game-mechanics, unreal

i've got a question about my unreal blueprints. I've been trying to get this right for almost a month now, but i don't know how to fix this. These are my are down below and a small video to explain my situation better.

As you can see, i have 2 variables index_NUMB & index_num. My idea was to make a weapon that i could pickup with a button when i'm in range and drop with my "hand". But of course not to destroy all weapons when i pick one up, that is why i wanted to use 2 index variables. But the result is as in my little vid, i can pick up the objects and drop them just fine for only one time and then i can only pickup the wrong one. When i for example pick up the first one it picks up the other one, and vice versa.

I've particularly noticed that when i have dropped the items it sets them to the same index value and then Unreal can't make the distiction anymore between wich one to pick up.

Does anyone see what i've done wrong here or does anyone know how to fix this? Links, tutorials, etc. are all good.( I really want this fixed!) Thanks in advance for reading and/or helping me!!

Video + pictures:
https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public/UnrealProblemMap
[image]
[image]